# Aggregate initialization of a derived class

Tags: c++, initialization

The following code does not compile with either Visual Studio2017 or online GDB. I expected it to compile as iterator is just a class with types and it is inherited from publicly. Is this not allowed or doesnt this work in VS2017?

```
template<typename T>
struct Gen : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T>
{
    T value;
};

int main()
{   
    Gen<int> g = Gen<int>{ 10 }; // this doesnt
    Gen<int> g2 = Gen<int>{ {}, 10 }; // neither does this
}
```

The error is

> Error C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to
>   'Gen'

Comment: Compiler options?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What

```
Gen<int> g = Gen<int>{ 10 };
```

tries to do is calling the non-existent `Gen<int>(int)` constructor. What you want to do is *aggregate initialization* whose syntax is:

```
Gen<int> g = { {}, 10 };
```

And [**only works since C++17**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) for derived types:

> If the initializer clause is a nested braced-init-list (which is not an expression), the corresponding array element/class member **/public base (since C++17)** is list-initialized from that clause: aggregate initialization is recursive.

---

For more information, *aggregate initialization* is defined in the following standard sections.

> #### [`[dcl.init.list]/3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3)
>
> 3. List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>    3.1 If the *braced-init-list* contains a *designated-initializer-list*, T shall be an aggregate class.

and

> #### [`[dcl.init.aggr]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#1)
>
> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 12) with
> 1.1 no user-provided, explicit, or inherited constructors (15.1),
> 1.2 no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 14),
> 1.3 no virtual functions (13.3), and
> 1.4 no virtual, private, or protected base classes (13.1).

Because in inherits from `std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T>`.

Comment: So, why Get<int> isn't an aggregate? I don't see where inheritance is forbidden.

Comment: `Gen<int> g = { {}, 10 };` - it doesn't work, maybe it is not implemented yet, i dunno

Comment: @Yola. its done. See updated version. C++17 required.